# How to listen onClick event for notififation bar on Android?

Tags: android, notifications

Well, I have a simple notification. But when I tap it in Notification bar, I just get opened my app. So how can I know that my app was opened by notification tap or how can I open a specific Activity after tapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have this code in `Statusbar Notification`. When you click the Notification Item, the following `Intent` is called.

```
    Context context = ctx.getApplicationContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, ctx.getClass());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

If you want specific `Activity` to be opened, call the particular Class in the above `Intent`

Answer (score 2):

There is no onClick event on a notification. It is merely launching a prepackaged PendingIntent that is attached to **THAT** specific notification object.

Comment: Is this possible if I have multiple intents(same application), any all are of different kind. i.e. I have a parameter in payload by which I can identify. But I want to attach this payload to correspond pending intent.I mean If I have 5 notifications, and click on the first come notification, I got the payload related to the recent coming notification.
That is the problem here...

Comment: but is there any way to know...intent has been launched from same component where u wrote code...not in new launched element(service/activity)?